# Computing even and odd monents/Moment Generating Function

Tags: statistics

I have the probability distrubition function $p(x)=2\lambda xe^{(-\lambda x^2)}$ if $x\ge0$ and $=0$ if $x\lt 0$, where $\lambda \gt 0$.

I have to show that the even moments of this distribution are given by $\Bbb E[X^{2n}]= {n!\over\lambda^n }$ for $n=0,1,2, etc.$ and that the odd moments of this distribution are given by $\Bbb E[X^{2n+1}]= {(2n+1)!\over\ 2^{2n+1}\lambda^n n! }$ for $n=0,1,2,etc.$

Now, I have two options. Either, to use the moment generating function or to use the normal formula for $E[X^{n}]=\int\ _\Bbb R x^n p(x)dx$. Or is there another method which involves less complicated integration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not computed, but am pretty sure the odd moments should have $\pi$'s in them.

Comment: Where should the pi's be?

Comment: Let us calculate, for example the first moment, for $\lambda=1/2$. We get $\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$. Integrate by parts, letting $u=x$ and $dv=xe^{-x^2/2}\,dx$. When we integrate, we get $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$. This is familiar, I think it is $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the second approach and the substitution $t = \lambda x^2$. Your integral becomes a $\Gamma$-integral. The distinction between even and odd cases will then come from properties of the $\Gamma$-function.

Comment: So with this substitution I get ${dt\over dx}=2\lambda x \Rightarrow dx= {dt\over 2\lambda x}$

We also have that $x= \sqrt{t\over \lambda}$

Putting this all together gives me $$E[X^{n}]=\int_0^\infty \left(\sqrt{t\over \lambda}\right)^ne^{-t} dt $$
I'm not sure how this exactly related to the $\Gamma$-integral you mentioned. Can you please explain?